# How do I change the highlight color for selected text with Emacs / deftheme?

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 24; I've installed the **zenburn** theme, which is great, except I cannot see the selection highlight easily with the highlight color provided by **zenburn**:

[image]

By **"selection"** color, I mean the color of text that I've selected by setting a mark (`C-space` and moving the cursor to select text).

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to change it. I've tried changing every combination of `highlight`, `selection`, etc.. that I can think of in `zenburn-theme.el`, but nothing seems to change it.

**For sanity's sake, I've tried changing other colors in the theme to make sure Emacs is loading the file properly - it is - those changes work.*

I would have especially thought that changing `highlight` would work, but no customizations to the `highlight` line seem to work:

```
;;;; Built-in                                                                                                                                                                            
;;;;; basic coloring                                                 
   ...                                                                                                      
   `(highlight ((t (:background ,zenburn-bg-05 :foreground ,zenburn-yellow))))
```

How can I change the selection color?

Comment: `M-x customize-face` will allow you to modify the face at cursor.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `region` face. For example:

```
(set-face-attribute 'region nil :background "#666")
```

Comment: This does not apply for the selected texts on `isearch`, is there any way to change background color on the searched texts as well?

Comment: @alper `isearch` uses a different face, a quick look at `isearch.el` reveal that it is quite complicated since `isearch` seems to be using `highlight-regex` for highlighting. You'll probably need to dig in a bit further to find the face name that you want.

Answer (score 46):

In addition to tungd's solution. You could also then change the font color to make it more readable. E.g. to white

```
(set-face-attribute 'region nil :background "#666" :foreground "#ffffff")
```

Comment: Just as a heads-up to Emacs n00bs like myself, this solution is complete, but it also overwrites any syntax-highlighting you have on the selected region because of the `foreground`.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the **customize** interface.

```
M-x customize-face
```

When prompted for which face, enter **`region`**.  Then you'll see
something like:

[image]

Using *customize* makes it easy to experiment with lots of colors.  Try
clicking `[ Choose ]` to access the color-picker), then
`[ Apply and Save ]`.  It also nicely organizes your customizations
into a single file (rather than further polluting your `init.el`).